# What's the fastest way in TortoiseGIT to switch to a remote branch having its name in clipboard?

Tags: switch-statement, checkout, tortoisegit

what's the fastest and easiest way in TortoiseGIT to switch to a branch remotes/origin/feature/xxx having name `feature/xxx` in the clipboard? I'm always going with context menu on repository directory, TortoiseGit -> Switch/Checkout and then scroll through Branch dropdown. It's quite tedious, esp. with high number of branches on remote. Doing this often made me think if I do it wrong (ineffeciently)?
I'm looking for a simple input field I could paste the branch name into

Thanks

Comment: For me using CLI is faster here than TortogiseGit. Just type `git checkout feature/xxx` in your terminal. To insert branch name from clipboard use `Shift+Insert`.